# Solution of the following matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to find the unique solution $D$ to the following equation:

$$ D = A^T W^{-1} A + W^{-1} - (A^T W^{-1})^T D^{-1} (A^T W^{-1}) , $$

where $W, D$ are Symmetric Positive Definite (SPD) matrices.

(A scalar version of the above would lead to a quadratic equation in $D$ and I want to find the unique solution to this equation given that it exists)

Comment: How do you know there is a unique solution?

Comment: @Alex -- I know that $D$ is positive definite and it can be shown that it is decreasing if the relation were written in a recursive form for $D$. So, I think that a fixed point should exist?